# Weird behavior using the Swift Optional type

Tags: swift, generics, option-type

I was practicing with Swift Optional type a little bit, and noticed weird(for me) behavior. Code:

```
func returnOptionalIntFromString(_ val: String) -> Int? {
    return Int(val)
}

func returnIntFromString(_ val: String) -> Int {
    return Int(val) ?? 0
}

let optionalStr: String? = "10"
let mappedC1 = optionalStr.map(returnIntFromString)
let mappedC2 = optionalStr.map(returnOptionalIntFromString)
let flatMappedC1 = optionalStr.flatMap(returnIntFromString)
let flatMappedC2 = optionalStr.flatMap(returnOptionalIntFromString)
```

Why this line `let flatMappedC1 = optionalStr.flatMap(returnIntFromString)` compiling? I'm passing `(String) -> Int` to the function which accept `(String) -> Optional<Int>`, so it must be compile-time error? Or no? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optionals are treated specially by the compiler. In particular, a value
of type `T` is automatically wrapped into an `Optional<T>` if necessary:

```
let a = 5
let b: Int? = a
```

That works also with non-optional vs optional return types of
a closure:

```
let cla: () -> Int = { return 13 }
let clb: () -> Int? = cla
```

and that is what happens in

```
let flatMappedC1 = optionalStr.flatMap(returnIntFromString)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have to say that all variables in the example are Optional

```
let optionalStr: String? = "10"
let mappedC1 = optionalStr.map(returnIntFromString)
let mappedC2 = optionalStr.map(returnOptionalIntFromString)
let flatMappedC1 = optionalStr.flatMap(returnIntFromString)
let flatMappedC2 = optionalStr.flatMap(returnOptionalIntFromString)
print(optionalStr, mappedC1, mappedC2, flatMappedC1, flatMappedC2)
```

yeilds:

`Optional("10") Optional(10) Optional(Optional(10)) Optional(10) Optional(10)`

Yeah! 'Optional world' has come! :)

So, `let flatMappedC1 = optionalStr.flatMap(returnIntFromString)` should read this way:

if `optionalStr` is not nil let's unwrap "10" and use flatMap function where `returnIntFromString` has got non-optional parameters. the function `returnIntFromString` returns `Int` which could be simply converted into `Int?` as @MartinR said. The function `flatMap` yeilds `Int?`. if `optionalStr` is nil `flatMappedC1` yeilds nil.